# How do I eliminate the possibility of simultaneous aceess of a Notes Document

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In our project we have the following:

A list of Notes documents with fields:

1. Our System's user ID (our name)
2. System B's Auth Object (their name)
3. System B's token

I decided to write a Java method for updating the token (every 30 minutes). Basically, it'll iterate through the list, execute a REST method to their system and finally we'll get a new token and write it to the document. There are not so many documents (in fact, always fewer than 10, but the request can take a lot of time)

However, I stumbled upon a problem. What if a user's request will be executed simultaneously with token refreshing? How should we treat such a case? Should I have something like a lock for eliminating such a possibility? And in the code of each user's request we should send a request only if the document is unlocked? How can we "wait" for that unlock?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if the token is not refreshed after 30 mins, and a user request is exectued? And if the request is blocked until the token is refreshed, what happens when a timeout for the token refresh occurs?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to store the token in memory only and refresh it when a user request comes in (and the token is expired)?

Comment: And what happens if you have 2 replicas of the database?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the default Locking mechanism in Notes: document locking needs to be enabled in Database Properties. Then you can do the following:

```
If doc.lock( timestamp ) then 
    'Document has not been locked previously
    'Your code comes here
    'Don‘t forget to unlock at the end
End if
```

Parameter usually is a username, so why use a timestamp as a „pseudouser“? The „locking“ user is always the signer of the code, you need to differentiate between the different calls, so use a timestamp to identify the session uniquely.

Comment: FYI: Document Locking is enabled by default - test it and see.  The 'allow document locking' database property is badly labelled.  It should say 'allow document locking across replicas' or something similar.

Comment: Yes, softlocking is enabled by default, but this does not „mark“ the document as locked so that you can use it as flag...

Comment: Why would you need to use a flag, when by default a second user clicking edit on the same document in the same instance of a database is locked out by default?

Comment: However it's not clear from the OP that they are talking about a use case in a Notes client.  Notes Document Locking does not work on the web, but it's possible to write a web based document locking process.